# Access subtract form value from another query

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access using VBA trying to subtract a calculated value (time between dates) from a total amount of time in another table.

The query holding the total amount of time is QryScsBatchHandler the field I want to subtract the value from is FreezerLifeUsed and the match condtion is BatchID

The query holding the value I want to subtract is QrySCSMaterialFreezerLog or the form is Frm_MaterialFreezerLog.. the value is AccumilatedTime and the Match condition is Batch ID

```
Private Sub BkInFrzr_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "SELECT FreezerLifeUsed FROM QryScsBatchHandler WHERE [BatchID] = BatchID"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rst
   .MoveFirst
    .Edit
     FreezerLifeUsed = -AccumilatedTime
     .Update
End With

End Sub
```

I can’t seem to get this simple subtraction to work… any suggestions on what’s not right?

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: `!FreezerLifeUsed = !FreezerLifeUsed - AccumilatedTime`. Accumilated is a misspelling of Accumulated. Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea. What is AccumilatedTime - a textbox on form? `Me.AccumilatedTime`.

Comment: Hi June7.. Yes it is a text box on a form... Ill correct the dodgy spelling when i have it working at the moment its still not updating... I've changed the rst statement to... rst!FreezerLifeUsed = Me.AccumilatedTime.Value is the parenthesis correct on the strSQL statement... that's normally what catches me out

Comment: There are no parentheses - there are brackets and they are fine. However, if the query returns only one record, why a loop? Also, instead of opening a recordset, an UPDATE action would work. Your last effort does not subtract. What is statement for QryScsBatchHandler? You need to concatenate BatchID: `WHERE [BatchID]=" & Me.BatchID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least 3 issues with code.

1. concatenate reference to form field/control for dynamic criteria in SQL:
   `strSQL = "SELECT FreezerLifeUsed FROM QryScsBatchHandler WHERE [BatchID] = " & Me.BatchID`
2. The VBA needs to use dot or bang when referencing controls or fields and qualifying with prefix is advised:
   `!FreezerLifeUsed`
   `Me.AccumilatedTime`
3. Nothing is subtracted from anything, so consider:
   `!FreezerLifeUsed = !FreezerLifeUsed - Me.AccumilatedTime`

However, if query is expected to return only one record, don't bother with loop. Also, instead of opening a recordset, an UPDATE action would work.

Comment: Thanks for your help June7... its pretty much as you describe above, I was still struggling with it not updating but defining the !FreezerLifeUsed - AccumilatedTime as string was the fianl piece... Thanks very much